# Dynamic nginx proxy_pass url mapping with code

Tags: web-services, nginx, reverse-proxy

sorry for the dense title.

I'd like a way to dynamically map the proxy_pass url in my nginx config.  I'd prefer the logic that does this be in any language, because I might need to call some web services.  For example..

```
Request url: http://example.com/id-a
Proxied url: http://partner-domain.com/123
```

The mapping from id-a to 123 is non-trivial, and as mentioned, may have some impure dependencies (such as a web service call).  However, the calls will be fast, as I expect to have great performance.  This is why I'm not confident about, say, having python/flask make the proxy; nginx is very good at it.  However, they are fast enough to make the mapping, but I don't know how to give the result back to nginx to work with.

Any ideas?